# mod_rewrite $_GET

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a `FrontController` expecting two `$_GET` params:

```
controller
action
```

A typical call to the site would look like this:

> http://foo.bar/index.php?controller=start&action=register

What I want to do is to allow the user to visit this site by the following url:

> http://foo.bar/start/register

What I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Since this gives me 404 Errors it doesn't seem to work.

`mod_rewrite` itself is enabled on the server.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but there are already many frameworks out there. Use one. Symfony2 for example.

Comment: Where did you place the rewrite rules -- httpd.conf or .htaccess? If it is in a .htaccess file then which one? The one inside root directory or somewhere inside a sub folder?

Comment: .htaccess, in a subfolder.
The whole project is located in a subfolder, so the real-world url looks something like this: http://foo.bar/project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.htaccess` you posted works for me:

```
// GET /cont1/action1

print_r($_GET);

/* output
Array
(
    [controller] => cont1
    [action] => action1
)
*/
```

You might want to try an absolute path to `index.php` rather than a relative one.

Regardless, that regex will result in:

```
// GET /cont1/action1/arg1

print_r($_GET);

/* output
Array
(
    [controller] => cont1/action1
    [action] => arg1
)
*/
```

You'd be better off doing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And having your `index.php` split up the `$_GET['url']` into controller, action, args, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to getting this working. If you are working with PHP and Apache, rewrite engine must be available on your server.

In your user folder put a file named `.htaccess` with these contents:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then your `index.php` you can use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable to see what was requested:

```
<?php
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'); 
echo $path;
?>
```

If someone requested `/start/register`, then assuming all the above code is in the html root, the `$path` variable would contain `start/register`.

I'd use the explode function on `$path` using the `/` as a separator and pull the first element as register.

The rewrite code has the benefit of working with filenames and directory names.